# Filter by any of subdocuments filed's value

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDB to store some data. Documents have some mandatory fields and a set of optional. There can be any number of optional fields (this is metadata):

```
class DataItem {
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [BsonExtraElementsAttribute]
    BsonDocument Metadata { get; set; }     
}
```

Metadata field names might be different for different documents, so I do not know these names.

I need to query such documents where any filed of Metadata contains a particular value.

I tried:

```
var query = "<some value>";
var res = collection.Find(di => di.Metadata.ContainsValue(BsonValue.Create(query))).ToListAsync();
```

But this code throws exception because ContainsValue() method is not supported there. When I try this:

```
var res = collection.Find(di => di.Metadata.Values.Contains(BsonValue.Create(query))).ToListAsync();
```

an empty result set is returned. I think the problem is in [BsonExtraElementsAttribute] but I cannot change it. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Querying on extra elements isn't currently supported. File a feature request ticket at jira.mongodb.org under the CSHARP project.